# Azure Function Proxy Regex Match Condition Route

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to create a match condition route that matches several directories that I would like to adjust the `Cache-Control` header for. At the moment I have this:

```js
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "Locales": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/locales/{*url}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://backend.com/locales/{url}",
            "responseOverrides": {
                "response.headers.Cache-Control": "max-age=1209600"
            }
        },
        "App": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/app/{*url}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://backend.com/app/{url}",
            "responseOverrides": {
                "response.headers.Cache-Control": "max-age=1209600"
            }
        },
        "Fonts": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/fonts/{*url}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://backend.com/fonts/{url}",
            "responseOverrides": {
                "response.headers.Cache-Control": "max-age=1209600"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I am doing the same thing with all three of these proxies, it would be nice if I could combine them into one with a regex match condition or something similar.

Is it possible to write a regex expression to match all of these routes? [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) do not seem to cover anything like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex match on route is not currently supported.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude a route from a proxy function?